# Is it legal to refer to this pointer and hook up a lambda from inside the constructor of a class?

Tags: c++, lambda, constructor, c++14, this-pointer

**Scenario:**
I have class like below which hooks up a lambda in the constructor itself. And the lambda calls a class member function in turn.

**Code:**

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    typedef std::function<void(int)> Callback;
    void ListenForCallback(const Callback& callback) {
        m_callback = callback;
    }
private:
    Callback m_callback;
}

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {
        m_some_class = std::make_unique<SomeClass>();

        // Here in constructor itself I pass this pointer and hooking up to a lambda which calls a member function. Is this legal?
        m_some_class->ListenForCallback([this](int value) {
            std::cout << "Value is: " << value << std::endl;
            TakeAction();
        })
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> m_some_class;

    void TakeAction() {
        // Please do something
    }
}
```

**Question:**
I was skeptical about using the `this` pointer in the `MyClass`'s constructor itself. And even further skeptical about hooking up a lambda calling a member. But, I found that above code works! Am I doing everything legal and correct in above code?

Is it valid to refer to `this` pointer in the constructor of a class? I wish to know if its valid/invalid and the explanation or reasoning behind the answer.

**Environment:**
C++ 14 code compiled with Clang and GCC compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. The object of the class `MyClass` exists at this point. So the pointer `this` is valid, and of course the class `someClass` has been completely constructed as well.

The only thing to watch out for is the order of member initialisation of `MyClass` - but only really in the initialiser list, although since you are not using an initialiser list here it is not an issue in this example anyway...

Comment: Ah. Such a relief to know that its legal.

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg I know the feeling, I have asked a bunch of these types of question in my time as well : )

Answer (score 1):

It can appear within the body of any non-static member function.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this

Constructors are non-static member functions, so it is legal.

Comment: It's not official documentation, but it is a fabulous website, and they tend to fix mistakes quickly (and even moreso if a mistake is brought to there attention) and try to keep abreast of the evolving standard.